# ROR Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 models: `Purchase` and `User`. `User` `has_many :purchases`, and `Purchase` `belongs_to :user`.   I want to select the following:

How many distinct users have made a purchase in the last 3 months, and also a way to print their email addresses ('Purchase' has a created_at field) (I want to just do this using the console). I'm a little confused as to how to go about it from a ruby perspective (I could do the straight SQL query, but I'd like to figure out how to do it in Ruby).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rails 2: Purchase.all(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", 3.months.ago]).user.uniq

Rails 3: Purchase.where(:created_at > 3.months.ago).user.uniq
```

Comment: When I try the .user.uniq I get: NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<Array:0x7cb6360> (Rails 2 btw)

Comment: Try `Purchase.all(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", 3.months.ago]).map(&:user).uniq`

Answer (score 1):

```
User.joins(:purchases).where("purchases.created_at > ?", 3.month.ago)
To get distinct user list
User.joins(:purchases).where("purchases.created_at > ?", 3.month.ago).uniq
To get distinct collection of user emails
User.joins(:purchases).where("purchases.created_at > ?", 3.month.ago).uniq.pluck(:email)
```

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on the data structure and how many record u would have.
If that's in a console which is on ur dev environment do whatever u like, otherwise good sql query will perform better.

1. Select field which are needed, use pluck where possible to get ids.
2. Use those ids to do a straight query.
   To do comparison <> u will have to use sql. 
   If u only need emails, add a select to the query so you would have 'select email from users;' instead of 'select * from users'.

so:

```
User.joins(:purchases).where('purchases.created_at > ?', .month.ago).pluck('distinct(email)')
```

will return you an array of your users' emails

apart from that have u bothered to read  [this?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and tried [that?](https://stackoverflow.com/search)

Answer (score -1):

`Purchase.where(:created_at > 3.months.ago).map(&:user).uniq`